# How to build android system source code in macOSX10.6?

Tags: android, macos

I downloaded the source code of android system. And I tried to run make. And I got the following message.

You are building on Mac OSX 10.6.
Can not find SDK 10.5 at /Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.5.sdk

Should I vi the build/core/combo/HOST_darwin-x86.mk and change the occurrence of MacOSX10.5.sdk into MacOSX10.6.sdk? Beacuse I can find the file MacOSX10.6.sdk.

Thanks and best regards.

Answer (score 1):

Create a symbolic link to have the compiler use the 10.6 SDK.

```
sudo ln -s /Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.6.sdk /Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.5.sdk
```